# To match and extract multiple words from directory path using tcl

Tags: tcl

Trying to match a certain words in a directory path and extract the value, example

```
C:\working\Ever7\FILE\
```

I need to extract `Ever7` from the path and it works well

```
set seq $name

set aa [split $seq \\]

set bb [lsearch -inline $aa Ev*]

set seq_number $bb
```

Now my question is the `Ever7` it varys, means it will be other words, there are `Ever7, Mak, Inge, DM, FP, Lin`

How to add or change the above expression so that it can match `Ever7 or Mak or Inge or DM or FP or Lin`, if match those words, it will set to seq_number as the next line of the code.
It would be nice if can shows the change.

Comment: Whether `C:\working`  and `FILE`part is always constant ?

Comment: No, is not always constant

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the path segment of interest to you can be reliably found at a constant position, you may want to use Tcl's capabilities for introspecting on filesystem paths:

```
set fp "/working/Ever7/FILE"
set needles [list Ever7 Mak Inge DM FP Lin]

if {[lindex [file split $fp] 2] in $needles} {
    incr seq_number
}
```

Otherwise, without any guarantees, just run a loop over `[string match]` needles:

```
foreach needle $needles {
  if {[string match *$needle* $fp]} {
    incr seq_number
    break;
  }
}
```

This won't require your haystack being transformed into a Tcl list before.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer, by changing the code on set bb that line

```
set bb [lsearch -inline -regexp $mach {^[DM|Ever7|Inge|FP|Lin|Mak]+$}]
```

Comment: As Jerry points out, this is not what you want ... mind the meaning of brackets: `[]`